# Expectation of $\exp(X)$ when $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

> Let be $X \sim N(2,4)$. What is the mathematical expectation of
> $e^{X}$?

**My approach:**

Let be $Z=\exp(X)$, then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{F}_{Z}(z)&=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z)
\\&=\mathbb{P}(\exp(X)\leq z)\\&=\mathbb{P}(X\leq \ln z)\\ &=\mathbb{F}_X(\ln z)
\end{align*}

So,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Z)&=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} z \cdot f_{Z}(z)\\&=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} z \cdot \underbrace{f_{X}(\ln z)}_{\text{Is this correct?}}\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\cdot \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} z \cdot \exp\left ( - \frac{(\ln z - 2)^{2}}{8} \right ) dz
\end{align}

**My doubts:**

- Am I correct until this point?
- If it is necessary to compute that integral, do you have any hint?
- Is there another way, easier and faster, to compute that expectation?

I really appreciate your help! Thank you very much!

Comment: The integrand of "is this correct?" is not correct: a change of variables is slightly more complicated.   The limits of the integral should also change since $\exp(X)$ is never negative.  $Z$ has a [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) and one way to find its mean and other moments is to use the moment generating function of $X$

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[\exp({\text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2))}] = \mathbb{E}[\text{Lognormal}(\mu, \sigma^2)] = \exp\left(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)$, see [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of expectation,

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb E[e^X] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^x f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx \\[1ex]
&= \frac1{4\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x-\frac1{32}(x-2)^2}\,\mathrm dx \\[1ex]
&= \frac{e^{10}}{4\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac1{32}(x-18)^2}\,\mathrm dx
\end{align}$$

Can you see the PDF of another normal distribution here? (See [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician))

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning you are making use of the law of the unconscious statistician under the hood there.

Comment: Ha, I was not aware of this law! "... tendency to use the identity without realizing ..." is right. Added a link for reference